# How can breaking the ElGamal encryption scheme break the Diffie-helman protocol?

Tags: diffie-hellman, elgamal-encryption

I have been studying how ElGamal is a public-key algorithm built on top of the Diffie-Hellman key exchange but I got confused. How exactly could an attacker break the Diffie-Hellman protocol (i.e. compute $g^{ab} \bmod p$ efficiently given $p, \space g, \space g^a \bmod p$, and $g^b \bmod p$) if they can efficiently find the plaintext messages from their ciphertexts (encrypted using ElGamal)?

Comment: What do you mean by " they can efficiently find the plaintext messages from their ciphertexts"? Without a private key?

Comment: Hint: Write how the ciphertext is produced in ElGamal encryption (some of [this answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/79988/555) details it). Assume an algorithm that can find it. Add some bells and whistles to turn it into an algorithm that breaks Diffie-Hellman (more formally: use the hypothetical algorithm as a subprogram). Also, note the proper name of Martin Hellman.