# Hash ElGamal CCA approach

Tags: hash, elgamal-encryption, chosen-ciphertext-attack

With this Elgamal variant defined below, we have covered in lecture but I do not still understand how a CCA could work against it. Is the use of the homomorphic nature of the encryption something you could use?

$c=\langle g^r, \mathcal{H}(y^r)\oplus m \rangle$

What could be a CCA against this type?

Comment: Xor some string to the second component. Does it invalidate the ciphertext? Constructing a CCA2 adversary from that should be easy.

Comment: This basically falls against the same attacks as unauthenticated stream ciphers do.

Answer (score 2):

I refer to you to a nice explanation of the basic attack on the "native" ElGamal scheme: [How does chosen ciphertext attack on Elgamal work?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/20262/how-does-chosen-ciphertext-attack-on-elgamal-work/24951#24951)

The difference between the native and this hashed scheme you outlined above is that the hashed elgamal version allows to encrypt a m-bit string message for any m since you use XOR, as long as the hashing function you use can output m bits. In the native ElGamal scheme, you have to map m into a group element, which may or may not be OK depending on which group you use. See [`Boneh's paper: section 4.1`](http://crypto.stanford.edu/~dabo/pubs/papers/DDH.pdf). 
For example, it is not straightforward when using Ed25519 with the special encoding, but solutions exists such as the elligator mappings.